# Can I access .info/serverTimeOffset from REST API?

Tags: firebase

I have successfully used the .info/serverTimeOffset to manage clock skew value from the Javascript library.

However when trying to access from REST I get an error.

```
GET https://my-firebase-name.firebaseio.com/.info/serverTimeOffset/.json HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 0
Accept-Encoding: identity, deflate, compress, gzip
Accept: */*
HTTP/1.1 400
content-length: 32
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
cache-control: no-cache

{
  "error" : "Invalid path."
}
```

Is this or any of the .info values available from REST?

Answer (score 2):

The correct values for `.info/connected` and `.info/serverTimeOffset` don't really make sense from a REST call's perspective and are therefore unavailable. There isn't a reliable way to for the server to know the client's time while making a REST call to serverTimeOffset so the number cannot be calculated accurately. Similarly, there is no concept of "disconnected" since a HTTP request terminates after completion.